# Is there a Lagrangian that produces these equations? How can I find one if it exists?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, inverse-problems

Consider the two differential equations
\begin{align*}
\ddot{x}_{A} - \gamma(x_{A} + x_{B}) &= 0, \\
\ddot{x}_{B} + \gamma(x_{A} + x_{B}) &= 0
\end{align*}
where $\gamma$ is a constant.
I am looking either for a Lagrangian $L = L(x, \dot{x}, t)$ that can reproduce these equations or a proof that shows this is impossible.

Unfortunately, my initial question was framed too narrowly, so I will leave two questions (they're not exactly the same as you will see in the answers). The first one was my original one. The second one is my new one.

**Question 1.** Is there a function $L = L(x, \dot{x}, t)$ such that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_{A}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_{A}} = \ddot{x}_{A} - \gamma(x_{A} + x_{B}), \\
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_{B}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_{B}} = \ddot{x}_{B} + \gamma(x_{A} + x_{B})?
\end{align*}

**Question 2.** Is there a function $L = L(x, \dot{x}, t)$ such that when setting the Euler-Lagrange expressions to zero we obtain differential equations that yield the same solutions as my original differential equations?

---

After looking around, I found [the inverse problem for Lagrangians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem_for_Lagrangian_mechanics) giving the Helmholtz conditions. Let us define $f^{A}(x^{A}, x^{B}) = \gamma\cdot (x^{A} + x^{B})$ and $f^{B}(x^{A}, x^{B}) = -\gamma\cdot (x^{A} + x^{B})$ as in the wiki page, and let us define
$$\Phi_{j}^{i} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \frac{\partial f^{i}}{\partial \dot{x}^{j}} - \frac{\partial f^{i}}{\partial x^{j}} - \frac{1}{4} \frac{\partial f^{i}}{\partial \dot{x}^{k}} \frac{\partial f^{k}}{\partial \dot{x}^{j}}.$$
Here we easily obtain
$$ (\Phi_{j}^{i}) = \begin{pmatrix} -\gamma & -\gamma \\ \gamma & \gamma \end{pmatrix}. $$
Now the wiki page says that we need to find a non-singular symmetric matrix $g = (g_{ij})$ such that conditions $(\text{H}1)$-$(\text{H}3)$ in the wiki page are satisfied (see image at the bottom for conditions).
I found that
$$ g = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{3}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2} & 2 \end{pmatrix} $$
works, so I concluded that there should be a Lagrangian for my differential equations. However, I have not been able to find such any desired function that works.

---

**Questions:**

- Was my above reasoning in determining that a Lagrangian exists correct? Did I make a correct application of Douglas's theorem?
- Can anyone help me find a Lagrangian? I tried various functions, yet they all failed to produce the differential equations.
- If no one can give me an explicit answer, then can anyone tell me what steps I should take to construct a Lagrangian?

---

**Some references:**

- [The wikipedia page is here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem_for_Lagrangian_mechanics).
- [This is the link](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1941-050-01/S0002-9947-1941-0004740-5/) to Douglas's paper on the inverse problem for Lagrangians.
- [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333379) asks about the inverse problem, and the answers provide some references.
- [The thesis](http://www.unilim.fr/pages_perso/loic.bourdin/Documents/bourdin-thesis2013.pdf) referenced in the MSE post provides an interesting so-called explicit condition on page 67, but it is only stated for the 1D one particle case. **NOTE:** It seems their condition only works for problems similar to Question 1. In Example IV.1 they conclude that a damped oscillator doesn't have a Lagrangian for the general case. This is **true** in the context of Question 1, but **false** in the context of Question 2 as [this post demonstrates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632054). If you multiply the differential equation by an exponential, then a Lagrangian can reproduce the differential equation.
- The MSE post referenced Olver's *Applications of Lie groups to differential equations*.
- Relevant wikipedia image as of 12/6/2022 in case it gets edited:
  [image]

Comment: Irrelevant now, but a good approach would have been the ansatz $L(x, \dot{x}) = \sum_{j = A, B} \sum_{k = A, B} M_{j k} \dot{x}_j \dot{x}_k + U_{jk} x_j x_k$. Differentiate to determine $M$ and $U$ by equating like terms.

Comment: Please refrain from addressing more than one question, and asking three subsequent questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer **Question 2:** The role of $g$ in Douglas's theorem appears to be to "symmetrize" the potential terms.  (I gleaned this from the condition (H1) in the Wikipedia article.)  In particular, the fact that $g \Phi = (g \Phi)^T$ implies that multiplying a column vector containing the given equations by $g$ would be fruitful.  Doing this yields
\begin{align*}
\ddot{x}_{A} + \frac{3}{2} \ddot{x}_B + \frac{1}{2}\gamma(x_{A} + x_{B}) &= 0 \\
\frac{3}{2} \ddot{x}_A + 2 \ddot{x}_{B} + \frac{1}{2} \gamma(x_{A} + x_{B}) &= 0
\end{align*}
and so it seems that the desired Lagrangian is
$$
L = \frac{1}{2} \dot{x}_A^2 + \frac{3}{2} \dot{x}_A \dot{x}_B + \dot{x}_B^2 - \frac{1}{4} \gamma (x_A + x_B)^2. 
$$

As an aside, note that the above "kinetic term" is not positive definite.  This may or may not be relevant for your purposes.

Comment: Wow, truly amazing!

Comment: @MaximalIdeal:  You did the hard work by finding $g$;  all I did was figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 6):

For future reference I recite your differential equations
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_{A}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_{A}} = \ddot{x}_{A} - \gamma(x_{A} + x_{B}) \tag{EL1}\\
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_{B}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_{B}} = \ddot{x}_{B} + \gamma(x_{A} + x_{B})\tag{EL2}
\end{align}

---

Unfortunately I am not familiar with Douglas theorem. However I was able to find the following proof which gives an answer to **Question 1**:

If we assume our Lagrangian to be of the most general form $L=L(\dot {x}_A,\dot{x}_B,x_A,x_B,t)$ and we plug it in the first equation $(EL1)$
collecting the $\ddot{x}_A$ terms yields
$$
\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial \dot{x}_{A}^2}=1
$$
Thus, $L$ has to be a polynomial of second order in $\dot{x}_{A}$, or more specifically
$$
L(\dot {x}_A,\dot{x}_B,x_A,x_B,t)=\frac{\dot{x}_A^2}{2}+\dot{x}_A\cdot L_1(\dot{x}_B,x_A,x_B,t)+L_0(\dot{x}_B,x_A,x_B,t)
$$
Now we plug this into the second equation $(EL2)$ and collect the $\ddot{x}_A$ and $\ddot{x}_B$ terms and see that
$$
\ddot{x}_A:\qquad\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \dot{x}_{B}}=0\\
\ddot{x}_B\dot{x}_A: \qquad\frac{\partial^2 L_1}{\partial \dot{x}_{B}^2}=0\\
\ddot{x}_B:\qquad\frac{\partial^2 L_0}{\partial \dot{x}_{B}^2}=1
$$
which yields more refined representations of the functions $L0$ and $L1$, namely
$$
L(\dot {x}_A,\dot{x}_B,x_A,x_B,t)=\frac{\dot{x}_A^2+\dot{x}_B^2}{2}+\dot{x}_A\cdot \alpha(x_A,x_B,t)+\dot{x}_B\cdot \beta(x_A,x_B,t)+\lambda(x_A,x_B,t)
$$
Once again, plugging in the adjusted form in the two equations $(EL1)$ and $(EL2)$ we end up with three equations for the unknown functions $\alpha,\beta$ and $\lambda$.
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x_B}&=\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x_A}\tag{1}\\
\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x_A}&=-\gamma(x_A+x_B)\tag{2}\\
\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x_B}&=\gamma(x_A+x_B)\tag{3}
\end{align}
These equations look promising at first, however if we consider
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_B}\big(2)\big)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_A}\big((3)\big)\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial^2\alpha}{\partial t\partial x_B}-\frac{\partial^2\beta}{\partial t\partial x_A}=-2\gamma\\
\stackrel{(1)}{\Rightarrow}0=-2\gamma
$$
we see that a solution can only exist for the trivial case of $\gamma=0$.

edit: for the last step I considered $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ to be differentiable twice. If we relax this condition we might find a solution to the system $(1)-(3)$.

Comment: I think your proof is correct here that the equations as given can't come from a Lagrangian;  but that leaves open the possibility that some non-singular transformation of the equations *can* come from a Lagrangian.  In other words, the fact that there is no $\ddot{x}_B$ term in (EL2) does not imply that $\partial L_1/\partial\dot{x}_B = 0$. See my answer below.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yeah, this is my fault more than his, because I realized just now that I formulated my problem too narrowly. I'll try to edit my question to accommodate this.

Comment: Nonetheless, this post provides valuable information, so please don't delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it seems I was not versed enough in the topic to see the true question behind the problem! :-) However, thanks for editing the problem in a way that leaves my answer valid. I made an edit to clarify it is only an answer to Question 1.